# How to connect to MediaPlayer2.Player PlaybackStatus signal using pygtk?

Tags: python, linux, pygtk, dbus

I actually want to display the information about the media or song currently being played with a window as a popup containing the artwork and the song name etc. I read about that a

`PlaybackStatus`

signal is emitted whenever a media is playing or stopped. How would i connect to that signal, well I read about dbus and came to know that it can be accessed using the `org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties` interface. I have recently started development with PyGtk so I don`t know how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before doing this with Python I find it useful to experiment on the command line to see what the expected values are. This can be done with the `busctl` tool.

The media players are on the Session (or user) bus.

```
$ busctl --user list | grep -i MediaPlayer2
org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.firefox.instance62995  62995 GeckoMain       usera :1.99         user@1000.service -       -
```

I can use the name of the service to find the objects in the D-Bus tree:

```
$ busctl --user tree org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.firefox.instance62995
└─/org
  └─/org/mpris
    └─/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2
```

With the `name` and the `object path` the object can be introspected

```
$ busctl --user introspect org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.firefox.instance62995 /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2
NAME                                TYPE      SIGNATURE RESULT/VALUE              >
org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable interface -         -                         >
.Introspect                         method    -         s                         >
org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer           interface -         -                         >
.GetMachineId                       method    -         s                         >
.Ping                               method    -         -                         >
org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties     interface -         -                         >
.Get                                method    ss        v                         >
.GetAll                             method    s         a{sv}                     >
.Set                                method    ssv       -                         >
.PropertiesChanged                  signal    sa{sv}as  -                         >
org.mpris.MediaPlayer2              interface -         -                         >
.Quit                               method    -         -                         >
.Raise                              method    -         -                         >
.CanQuit                            property  b         false                     >
.CanRaise                           property  b         true                      >
.DesktopEntry                       property  s         "firefox"                 >
.HasTrackList                       property  b         false                     >
.Identity                           property  s         "Mozilla Firefox"         >
.SupportedMimeTypes                 property  as        0                         >
.SupportedUriSchemes                property  as        0                         >
org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player       interface -         -                         >
.Next                               method    -         -                         >
.OpenUri                            method    s         -                         >
.Pause                              method    -         -                         >
.Play                               method    -         -                         >
.PlayPause                          method    -         -                         >
.Previous                           method    -         -                         >
.Seek                               method    x         -                         >
.SetPosition                        method    ox        -                         >
.Stop                               method    -         -                         >
.CanControl                         property  b         true                      >
.CanGoNext                          property  b         false                     >
.CanGoPrevious                      property  b         false                     >
.CanPause                           property  b         true                      >
.CanPlay                            property  b         true                      >
.CanSeek                            property  b         false                     >
.MaximumRate                        property  d         -                         >
.Metadata                           property  a{sv}     5 "mpris:trackid" o "/org/>
.MinimumRate                        property  d         -                         >
.PlaybackStatus                     property  s         "Paused"                  >
.Position                           property  x         -                         >
.Rate                               property  d         -                         >
.Volume                             property  d         -                         >
.Seeked                             signal    x         -                         >
```

As you want to use Gtk it would seem sensible to use the D-Bus binding from https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

It will mainly be the [DBusProxy](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gio-2.0/classes/DBusProxy.html) that will be required.

An example of a window with a couple of labels for playback status and artist information might look like the following:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gio, Gtk


PLAYER_IFACE = 'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player'


class MainApp(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(title="Player Status")
        self.box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=6)
        self.add(self.box)
        self.lbl_status = Gtk.Label(label='Status Here')
        self.box.pack_start(self.lbl_status, True, True, 0)
        self.lbl_artist = Gtk.Label(label='Artist Here')
        self.box.pack_start(self.lbl_artist, True, True, 0)

    def update_label(self, proxy, changed_props, invalidated_props):
        props = changed_props.unpack()
        print(props)
        status = props.get('PlaybackStatus')
        artist = props.get('Metadata', {}).get('xesam:title')
        if status:
            self.lbl_status.set_text(status)
        if artist:
            self.lbl_artist.set_text(artist)


def find_player():
    """
    Find the first `org.mpris.MediaPlayer2` name in list
    """
    names = Gio.DBusProxy.new_for_bus_sync(
            bus_type=Gio.BusType.SESSION,
            flags=Gio.DBusProxyFlags.NONE,
            info=None,
            name='org.freedesktop.DBus',
            object_path='/org/freedesktop/DBus',
            interface_name='org.freedesktop.DBus',
            cancellable=None).ListNames()
    for name in names:
        if name.startswith('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2'):
            return name


def player_proxy(media_name):
    """
    Provide proxy for comfortable and pythonic method calls
    """
    return Gio.DBusProxy.new_for_bus_sync(
            bus_type=Gio.BusType.SESSION,
            flags=Gio.DBusProxyFlags.NONE,
            info=None,
            name=media_name,
            object_path='/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2',
            interface_name=PLAYER_IFACE,
            cancellable=None)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("running application")
    app = MainApp()

    player_name = find_player()
    player = player_proxy(player_name)
    # Connect signal to callback
    player.connect('g-properties-changed', app.update_label)

    app.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Thanks Man. I am grateful to you for your help. Cheers!

Comment: @uKBaz Dude, you rock! You're like a dbus GOD. Thanks for your answer. It helped a lot